# strongly typed view projected linq

Tags: linq, strong-typing

I have spent hours upon hours trying to figure out how to shape the data projected from linq to a strongly type view. My problem is I think my problem is I am unsure how to use IEnumberable and IGrouping.

Here is the linq:

```
var spec = from a in _entities.Approvals
                   join b in _entities.ApprovalSpecifications on a.HeaderlID equals b.HeaderlID into g
                   where a.ApprovalID == id
                   group a by a.HeaderlID into groupedByHeader
                   select new 
                   {
                       Key = groupedByHeader.Key,
                       groupedByHeader
                   };
```

Can anyone suggest the method with which I should approach this? I am thinking a class for this would work best, but as I mentioned I'm not sure how to use IGrouping to build a class. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your LINQ looks syntactically OK - so what are you trying to achieve and what isn't working?

Comment: When you say 'strongly typed view' are you talking about this sort of thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823438/linq-groupby-in-strongly-typed-mvc-view ?

Comment: I am trying to create a strongly typed MVC view. The query works great. My trouble is that I am not sure how to implement the class needed to enable this to be a strongly typed view.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class StronglyTypedGrouping {
  public object Key { get; set; } // I can't infer Key type from the snippet.
  public IEnumerable<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
}


var spec = from a in _entities.Approvals
           join b in _entities.ApprovalSpecifications on 
             a.HeaderlID equals b.HeaderlID into g
           where a.ApprovalID == id
           group a by a.HeaderlID into groupedByHeader
           select new StronglyTypedGrouping {
               Key = groupedByHeader.Key,
               Approvals = groupedByHeader
           };
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this type of thing, but when I have done this my view says there is no public definition for get enumerator. I think I am missing something obvious. Here is my class:

Comment: public class APRVViewModel
    {       
        public int Key { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<Approval> Approvals { get; set; }
    }

Comment: I don't understand "my view says there is no public definition for get enumerator." I think I need more context and a more specific compiler error message.

Comment: You need to build your view based on the StronglyTypedGrouping class. The variable spec will contain the set of StronglyTypedGrouping instances the query produces.

Comment: I understand how to make the view strongly typed to the grouping class, but what I don't know is how to make a viewmodel class that has a property for the grouping. I figured out another way to do this by using the linq GroupBy extensions and a nested for each in the view, but would rather create a proper viewmodel for this rather than doing it in the view.